# Recover files from past commit after you have included them in .gitignore

Tags: git

I had a file that used to be tracked and was part of several commits in my git history. At some point, at a later time, I included that file in my .gitignore. I am trying to recover that file. I have tried `git reset --hard <sha>` and I have tried `git checkout <branch/remote/file/etc>`. Non of those commands recovered that file, its does not appear in the working directory.

Note that I can see the file in my git history. I can look at the changes I've made to it and if need be I can just copy-paste what git shows me. But how do I just recover this file from earlier commit history? Reset and checkout do not seem to be working for me and I suspect its because after I commited that file to git I included it in .gitignore and commited.

[UPDATE]

I've tried removing .gitignore but it still can't recover the file. I reset back to a commit where the file existed and where it was not in .gitignore, but it still wont bring it back.

Comment: When you added this file to `.gitignore`, did you also remove it from the repository?  `.gitignore` doesn't control what gets checked _out_ of a repo, only what Git offers to add to your new commits.

Comment: Before I included it to `.gitignore` I had committed it to git in like 10 commits. But later I included it to `.gitignore` and committed `.gitignore`. I never removed it until now by accident. I haven't made any commits after having accidentally deleted the file from my working dir.

Comment: Then (as per my answer below), you can simply say: `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file` and you'll get your file back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking out the file specifically.  Using a commit you *know* to contain the file do this

```
git checkout <commit> -- path/to/file
```

Comment: I get a `error: pathspec 'colors' did not match any file(s) known to git.` error. The path that I'm using is relative to where .git is at. In other words the file was located in the root of repo so I did a `git checkout <sha> -- dirname`. Its actually a directory, not a file.

Comment: Do you have other changes in your working directory besides accidentally deleting this directory?

Comment: No other changes. Its all clean. I've tried git cloning a fresh repo and trying to `checkout` and `reset` but that file wont show and with `checkout` it keeps giving me that error.

Comment: Wait.  Cloning the repo from scratch (which should leave a new working copy checked out at `HEAD`) didn't get you the directory back?  Are you sure you didn't commit the deletion?  What does `git log --stat` tell you?

Comment: I was able to get the file back from a more far back commit. I combed through my git log, I never committed a delete for the dir. In fact I never deleted it until now. I tied in the missing parts from a hard backup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `.gitignore` file before running your command. (or move it out of the repository)

Something like

```
rm .gitignore
# If the reset doesn't work because of the change, you can add --force
git reset --hard <sha>
```

Comment: I gave it a shot but still nothing.